# EditText проблемы с setText("")

Tags: android, android-edittext

`AlertDialog` содержит поле `EditText`. При первом вызове `EditText` пустой, после того как мы что то вбиваем в него руками он это значение сохраняет и выводит при последующем вызове диалога. Мне  нужно что бы при каждом новом запуске `EditText` был пустой

Помогите пожалуйста.
Использую:`.setText("")` -так не работает, хотя сам метод работает `.setText("Что то")` то так работает.

Вот код:

```
    case IDD_SET_NAME:
    builder=new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    builder.setTitle("Name Title");

    EditText input = new EditText(this);
    input.setRawInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT);
    input.setHint("Example: ARMS");
    input.setText("");//Это не срабатывает
    builder.setView(input);

       builder.setPositiveButton("Create", onClickListener_DialogResetPin);
       builder.setNeutralButton("Cancel", onClickListener_DialogResetPin);

       // создание и показ диалога
       dialog = builder.create();
       dialog.show();

        Button btnOK = dialog.getButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_POSITIVE);
        btnOK.setOnClickListener(onClickListener_btnOK);

        break;
```

Comment: убери 

input.setHint("Example: ARMS");

и заработает

Comment: Нет тоже не работает

Answer (score 2):

Нужно в классе переопределить метод

```
protected void onPrepareDialog(int id, Dialog dialog) {
      super.onPrepareDialog(id, dialog);
    }
```

так как

```
   protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
      return super.onCreateDialog(id);
    }
```

вызывается только один раз при создании диалога. Всю изменяемую информацию нужно обновлять в onPrepareDialog